# How can I convert an SVG file to a format read by Cinema 4D as Vector (like Adobe Illustrator ai file)

Tags: converters, photoshop, vector-graphics, inkscape, cinema-4d

I have Cinema 4D, Photoshop and Inkscape.  I have a bunch of vector graphics stuff in Inkscape that I would like to bring in as vectors into Cinema 4D to make 3D objects. I have found tutorials that talk about using Photoshop to create an Adobe Illustrator `*.ai` file. If I make a path in Photoshop and save as an ai file I can import into Cinema 4D and it works. My problem is that if I import the Inkscape SVG file it comes in as a bitmap and I have retrace the image to create the path. That would be a lot of retracing.

I got uniconvertor and installed it via the "sudo python setup.py install".  If I use the command line to attempt to convert nothing happens.  If I look for help "uniconvertor --help" nothing happens.  No error no output.  Inkscape seems to use it because now I do not get errors when I did before it was installed.  But it really doesn't seem to be working.

So, my ultimate question is how can I take my Inkscape vector drawings and get them into Cinema 4D as a vector to make 3D objects of them (suspect being able to somehow convert to Adobe Illustrator ai file in the middle but don't know)?

Comment: can you use eps format for exchange?

Answer (score 2):

I use a tool called VectorMagic (http://vectormagic.com/home) it will take any image and convert it to EPS, SVG, PDF, AI, DXF and EMF. Works seamlessly with Illustrator, Corel, and others.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your SVG file from SVG to AI using [Convertio](https://convertio.co/de/vector-converter/)

[image: Inkscape to C4D]

In the above example, the captions (`length` and `wingWid`) were lost, but it is still acceptable for me. I am not sure why the text is lost.